# scripting SQL table only from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I take a table with data in it to be executed? I tried to do it from Create Table but the data is missing I could only import coloumns.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click on `Database -> Tasks-> Generate Script`. If this is SMS 2008 then in Advanced option you have option for Schema | Schema and Data | Data only. Choose Schema and Data.

Comment: yes but I want only 1 table not the whole database. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such an option in `SSMS`.
You can just run this kind of simple SQL

```
SELECT * 
INTO [MyNewTable]
FROM [MyOldTable]
```

Comment: is it a linked server?

Comment: -1 because .There is an option in Sql Management Studio in 2008 and above. In 2005 it was not there